# Why does Jetson TK1 hang at "Starting kernel ..."

Tags: u-boot

With freshly flashed L4T 21.8, the serial console stops with output like:

```
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 82000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x82000000
   Using Device Tree in place at 82000000, end 83014f2d

Starting kernel ...
```

How do I get serial output from the kernel?

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Answer (score 1):

When things stop after "Starting kernel...", across boards, there are usually two causes:

1. serial console isn't enabled right
2. kernel didn't have enough space to unpack itself and start printing to serial console.

The first thing to enable is serial console.  Make sure the kernel command line for TK1 includes:

`console=ttyS0,115200n8 earlycon=uart8250,mmio32,0x70006300 earlyprintk`

Two things are going on there: One is enabling normal serial console once boot gets far enough.  The other is enabling earlycon before the proper 8250 driver is initialized, so you can see early boot failures too.  This serial setup should get you output on the DB9 connector J1A2 (UART4) just like u-boot uses.

If you still don't have serial output with that, likely the issue is the kernel trashing the dtb while unpacking -- the default 16Mb between `0x81000000` kernel and `0x82000000` fdt is not enough for many kernels.  You need to move the fdt address up to make space.  Press the reset button, and interrupt the boot by pressing a key when prompted, then enter this in your u-boot command line:

```
set fdt_addr_r 0x83000000
saveenv
run bootcmd
```

This gets you 32MB of space for the kernel image for this boot, and thanks to `saveenv` also any following ones.

Comment: follow-up: It turned out that the 21.8 release had issues with bringing up PCIE (error 110 timeouts at boot time) on upstream Linux kernels.  The answer was to not use the 21.8 L4T release and its u-boot, but to instead use tegra-uboot-flasher, which already solves this fdt address problem.